# Track changes in AWS Cognito

Tags: amazon-web-services, identity, amazon-cognito

Is in AWS Cognito any possibility to track the changes?

I need track custom attributes, but useful can be track email changes or mobile number changes.

I check the triggers also and I cannot find proper solution. Maybe in AWS is some service, which can do it for me. Not sure about that.

Any idea can be high appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I am on the Cognito team. There is currently no lambda trigger for tracking attribute changes but we have heard this request many times in the past and this feature is very much on our backlog.

Comment: So, is there a backlog I can vote in? I would need a trigger when a user is added to a group (to do user notification). Seems like a pretty basic functionality.

Comment: Almost 5 years ago and there is still no solution or workaround to this. Only thing you can do is to write a proxy arround cognito which can lead to security issues..